# Evaluating an integral involving $(a-x)^ne^{-1/x}/x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, integration-by-parts

Let $a>0$ be a small parameter and consider a fixed integer $n\geq 0$. Is it true that
$$
\int_0^a \frac{(a-x)^n e^{-1/x}}{x^2}\ dx=n! a^{2n}e^{-1/a}(1+O(a))
$$
as $a\to 0$?

I have verified this for $n\leq 4$, essentially by applying integration by parts with the asymptotic
$$
\int_0^a \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}\ dx=ae^{-1/a}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^kk! a^k+O(a^{2n+1})\right]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $\alpha = \frac{1}{a}$ ($\alpha\rightarrow \infty$ as $a\rightarrow 0$)and $t=\frac{1}{x}$ so that the integral transforms as $$I(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha ^n}\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}\big(t-\alpha\big)^nt^{-n}e^{-t}dt.$$ Expanding the first term in the integrand $$I(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha ^n}\Big[\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n\choose r}(-\alpha)^r\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}t^{-r}e^{-t}dt\Big].$$The integral in above is the incmplete gamma function $\Gamma(-r+1, \alpha)$. Rewriting, one has $$I(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha^n}\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n\choose r}(-\alpha)^r \Gamma(-r+1, \alpha).$$ The asymptotics for the incomplete gamma function is $$\Gamma(n, \alpha)\sim \alpha^{n-1}e^{-\alpha}\Big[1+\frac{n-1}{\alpha}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{\alpha^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot\Big]$$ which in the current case,  can written as $$\Gamma(-r+1,\alpha)\sim\alpha^{-r}e^{-\alpha}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}(-1)^s\frac{(r+s-1)!}{(r-1)!}\frac{1}{\alpha^s}.$$ Using the above expressions, it can be easily verified that $$I(\alpha)\sim\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\alpha ^n}\Big[\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n\choose r}(-1)^r\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}(-1)^s\frac{(r+s-1)!}{(r-1)!}\frac{1}{\alpha^s}\Big].$$ Upon interchanging the summations, one has to look at sums of the form $$\frac{1}{\alpha^s}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r{n\choose r}\frac{(r+s-1)!}{(r-1)!}.$$Now, we may note that $$-\frac{d^s}{dx^s}x^{s-1}(1+x)^n=-\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n\choose r}\frac{(r+s-1)!}{(r-1)!}x^{r-1}$$ The first non vanishing derivative at $x=-1$ occurs for $s=n$. The required estimate follows from here.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$\int_0^a \frac{(a-x)^n e^{-1/x}}{x^2}\ dx$$

Assume $u=-\frac{1}{x}$ 
 And $du=\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ 
Hence we have that as $x=0 , u \to -\infty$ and $x=a , u=-\frac{1}{a}$

Thus the integrand becomes $$\int^{-\frac{1}{a}}_{-\infty} (a+\frac{1}{u})^n e^u\ du$$

Can you look for some recursion?

Comment: （-∞，-$\frac{1}{a}$）？

Comment: Thanks, typo corrected @Kai